# How to serve up specific IAP when user downloads app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

If we market specific in-app-purchase content to people who don't have our app, what is the best way to facilitate the consumer gaining access to that IAP, if they respond to that particular marketing campaign?

For example, it would be nice if there was an iTunes app store link we could provide for the app which had the IAP product identifier included.  When the app is downloaded and launched, the AppDelegate could get the product identifier in the launchOptions for the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I am looking any ideas here so I am not trying to limit the question to the above solution.  The example scenario above was meant to help explain what I was after.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Del

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient way of doing this. Apple specifically does not want developers to target individuals by their device. If a user downloads the app, perhaps you should allow them to enter a code or sign in and then choose the correct IAP accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  I wasn't ever looking to identify the individuals myself.  More just wanting to allow the user to have a more tailored experience.  They are after specific IAP content, why not provide a better way for them to get directly to it?  I may look at putting in an enhancement request with Apple.